# How -> operator is able to access structure data members whose name doesn't exist?

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, binary-tree

So I've created a binary tree data structure and I can't understand that how can you access pointer variables without their names?

Have a look at the code first

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node *givetree()
{
    struct node *newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    char choice;
    
    printf("Enter data : ");
    scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
    
    printf("\nWanna fill left of %d ? (y/n) : ",newnode->data);
    scanf("%c",&choice);
    
    if(choice == 'y')
    newnode->left = givetree();
    
    printf("\nWanna fill right of %d ? (y/n) : ",newnode->data);
    scanf("%c",&choice);    

    if(choice == 'y')
    newnode->right = givetree();
    
    return newnode;
}

int main(void) {
    struct node *root = givetree();
    printf("\nThis works : %d",root->left->left->data);

    return 0;
}
```

So how the line `printf("\nThis works : %d",root->left->left->data)` works completely fine? The tree is created using recursion so the pointer named `root` receives a pointer to the root node, but how the pointer root is able to access structure data member named `left` if local variables names have been destroyed after the execution of function call?

I know they are present in the memory and retains their data but how we can access them if their names have been destroyed?

Comment: All variable names are destroyed during compilation, not just those behind pointers. Accessing `left` is possible because the compiler has the definition of `struct node` from which it knows at which offset from `root` the member `left` resides.

Comment: `left` isn't a local variable.  It's the name of a structure element.  It exists as long as the containing structure exists.

Answer (score 2):

`root` is a pointer to `struct node`.

`struct node` has the members `data`, `left`, `right`. Consequently you can do these 3 accesses:

```
root->data
root->left
root->right
```

As `left` is a pointer to `struct node`, `root->left` is a a pointer to `struct node`. Consequently you can do these 3 accesses:

```
root->left->data
root->left->left
root->left->right
```

Once again `root->left->left` is a a pointer to `struct node`. Consequently you can do these 3 accesses:

```
root->left->left->data
root->left->left->left
root->left->left->right
```

And so on...and so on... As long as you don't exceed the depth of your binary tree.